# how to create a plugin for web application to calculate the each and every invoked method execution time

Tags: java, jsf

My application file (EAR) consists of combination of EJB and WAR. FrameWork is JSF and IDE is Netbeans 6.9.1 applition server is glassfich V2.x. I want to calculate the execution time fro each and every invoked method in my application. i have gone through so many blogs. most of them suggested to use AOP. but nobody tell me how to configure and how to use it in my application. could anybody tell me ragarding this.  I have some code here and i made use of AOP and JAMon to calculate the method execution time. but i confused about how to configure this because for every method invocation this calss should be invoked  for that what to do i dont know. could anybody give some suggestions on it.If you any additional details to answer this i will provide. Code is:

```
public class PerformanceMonitorIncptr implements MethodInterceptor{

/** Creates a new instance of PerformanceMonitorIncptr */
public PerformanceMonitorIncptr() {
}
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
    String mName = mi.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." + mi.
            getMethod().getName();
    Monitor mon = MonitorFactory.start(mName);
//    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object returnValue = null;
    try {
        returnValue = mi.proceed();
    } finally {
        mon.stop();
        System.out.println(mon);
    }
    System.out.println(mName);
//    System.out.println(l - System.currentTimeMillis());
    return returnValue;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AOP is best suited here.

You need to configure `@PointCut` `@Around` each method you want to log the time of execution

Have a look at [this](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/01/spring-aop-example-profiling-method-execution-time-tutorial/)  tutorial .

**Update**

I hope 20 methods you are talking about /can be are Spring Service methods, and you don't need to alter them at all you just need to configure a `@Aspect` that will involve all the methods. [read more](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/aop.html#aop-pointcuts)

Comment: suppose I have 20 methods which were involved in save edit and delete operations. so i need to add these '@pointcut' and '@around' annotations to 20 mthods?

Comment: and my another question is any possibility to configure the above performanceMonitorIncptr class?

Comment: Spring can be easily configured with JSF with just nearly 5 line of conf

Comment: can you tell me the procedure any way

Comment: could you tell me that is it possible to create interceptor in WAR module to profile war module managed-beans

Comment: yes i defined beans.xml file in that i deifned interceptor and i configure this xml file in web.xml but no profiling has been done

Comment: Hi JigarJoshi, I used AspectJ with integrating with spring now i am getting the expected result. thank you very much for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

AOP is the solution.

But why would you write it yourself.

Use Javamelody -> [EJB configuration documentation](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide?tm=6#8._Business_facades_%28ejb-jar.xml_file_if_EJB3%29).

We use it with Spring, and it's great. There are also such solutions as AppDynamics, DynaTrace, NewRelic, JXInsight, CorrelSense, Nastel.
As for me Javamelody is free, opensource and very easy to use.

Comment: may be this is for EJB's right not for normal java classes right?

Comment: is there any possibility to configure the above calss to be called for every method invocation in my application (jsf framework) ?

Comment: You have to tell a bit more about your application stack. Do you use JSF 2.0 ? How do You create managed beans you want to monitor. Do you use EJB 3.0 or 3.1 and JEE 6? I think that you should have EJB beans with business logic and theese are objects to monitor.

Comment: i am using jsf1.2,EJB 3.0 and JEE 5

Comment: My application file is combination of EJB + WAR. ejb contains all ejbs and war contains web stuff and contollers (ManagedBeans) to access EJB's. so we define all these controllers in faces-controller-config.xml file and this xml file was configured in web.xml.

Comment: Hi i have used AspectJ to solve this. now i am getting expected result thank you for valuable suggestions

Comment: EJB provides @ArounInvoke interceptor (http://weblogs.java.net/blog/meeraj/archive/2006/01/interceptors_wi.html). AspectJ is a good solution too.